# npm does not support Node.js vX.X.X (current)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, chocolatey

I'm installing the current Node.js (as of today: 13.12.0) bundled with npm. However, the latest npm version (as of today: 6.14.4) does not support the current Node.js version resulting in this error:

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v13.12.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
```

I am using Chocolatey with the command `choco install nodejs` to install. This error also occurs when installing via the Node.js installer. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm always lags behind the current Node.js release. If you don't absolutely need the newest Node.js version for your use case I'd recommend installing the LTS (Long Term Support) version which is always supported by npm.

To do that follow these steps:

1. Uninstall Node.js either via your OS or if you are using Chocolatey: `choco uninstall nodejs`.
2. Install the LTS version with the installer found [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) or `choco install nodejs-lts` if you are using Chocolatey. The newest npm will be installed alongside both ways.
3. Restart your machine.